# Path of executable

Tags: windows, path, cmd, environment-variables

I have a few folders in my system's PATH variables that contain the exe-files with same name. So when I open a cmd and type a name of this exe-program I want to know from which directory it opens this exe. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`where your_exe` will tell you the version of `your_exe` that the shell will use.

Comment: Ok, so I have a list of folders as output of this command and cmd will run an exe from first-listed directory. Is it correct?

Comment: see here for a command that tells you which file will execute. I haven't checked to see if it's the first or not (though I suspect it is) http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-which.html

Answer (score 0):

A batch file:

```
@echo off
echo. 
echo PathFind - Finds the first file in in a path
echo ======== = ===== === ===== ==== == == = ====
echo. 
echo Searching for %1 in %path%
echo. 
set a=%~$PATH:1
If "%a%"=="" (Echo %1 not found) else (echo %1 found at %a%)
```